# How do I mock a callback in my FactoryGirl factory, using Rails 4.2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback, mocking, factory

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have this callback in my user model …

```
after_create :publish
…
  def publish
    Mymodule::Publisher.new_user(user: self, x_forward: {})
  end
```

I would like to mock this callback

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    …

  factory :user do
    after(:build) do |user|
      allow(user).to receive(:publish)
    end
```

But this results in a

```
 The use of doubles or partial doubles from rspec-mocks outside of the per-test lifecycle is not supported.
```

When I run all tests where

create(:user)

What’s another way I can mock this callback in the factory?

Comment: It looks like the mocking feature that supports `to receive` is not supported outside of a test (`it` or `specify` block).

Comment: Does it need to be in the factory? Could you mock the object in the test after it's built?

Comment: Hi @ajsharma, There are TONS of tests.  It would be possible but quite time intensive to modify each one.  I feel like there should be a global way to do this mocking when building the factory object, but not sure how that is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    # ... 
    after(:build) do |user|
      def user.publish
        # and here you can stub method response if you need
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't working.  The method defined directly in the class keeps getting called.

Comment: Strange. I have used this approach in my specs and it works

Comment: My bad, you are right.  I was getting into a situation where the factory after(:build) wasn't getting called.  Thanks for this!